# Convert Javascripts for IE10

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, internet-explorer-10, ecmascript-5

I need to convert this function to work with IE10.
I thought to use Babel to convert the file from ES6 to ES5, but i dont know how to use correctly Babel, because Babel dont convert Promise.
The script ES6 is this:

....

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0) {
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    resolve(allText);
                }
            }
        };
        rawFile.send(null);
    });
}
```

.....

Thanks so much for your help and your time.

Comment: `Promise` is an object/function, not syntax, so it won't be transpiled - use a polyfill instead

Comment: I used polyfill with Babel but dont convert.

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service. You need to try this yourself and post your effort.

Comment: I tried to use , https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill , but seems dont work, and now is deprecated.

Comment: If you are struggling setting up Babel into your ci, why don't you try using [Babel online](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) paste your code and select a specific browser or JavaScript version and watch the magic.

Comment: Tried already and dont convert Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed including this CDN in my HTML

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CPromise%2CPromise.prototype.finally%2Ces2016"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Promises is not compatible in IE
>
> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility

**Try look at the this package:** https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise